# Type 'SwiftUIWebView' does not conform to protocol'NSViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

I'm following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/MUVSRV4jXYE?t=453) on how to create a WebView in SwiftUI except that i'm making it for a macOS app and not IOS.

I switched UIViewRepresentable to NSViewRepresentable and i get this error: `Type 'SwiftUIWebView' does not conform to protocol'NSViewRepresentable'`

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import AppKit


struct SwiftUIWebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        
    }
    
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let myURL = url else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        uiView.load(request)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to use `makeNSView` protocol delegate instead of `makeUIView`.

```
struct SwiftUIWebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        return webView
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let myURL = url else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        nsView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nsviewrepresentable)

The methods are `makeNSView` and `updateNSView`.